# EasyPHP Dashboard Unable to load

Tags: easyphp

I have installed EasyPHP web server "EasyPHP-Webserver-14.1b2"

After installation i am able to access the dashboard 127.0.0.1:10000

however, after restarting my computer, i could not access the dashboard. it just keep loading and loading

Answer (score 22):

I also had the same problem. I ran the application as administrator, it worked for me.

Answer (score 4):

Reinstall it, at the end of the installer wizard uncheck the launch EasyPHP option. Then launch it yourself as admimistrator ( shortcut > right click > run as admin ). cheers

Answer (score 3):

To manually start the dashboard use this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\EasyPHP-Devserver-17\eds-dashboard\eds-dashboard.exe" -S 127.0.0.1:1111 -c eds-dashboard.ini
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. As Marcos posted I managed to get it working on his suggestion.
In the end, I created a batch file (filenameyouwant.bat) in the directory containing the default settings for me with this:

```
eds-dashboard.exe -S 127.0.0.1:1111 -c eds-dashboard.ini
cmd /k
```

Set a shortcut or whatever works for you to run the batch file whenever needed.

Answer (score 2):

Type this in address bar after installing and right clic on icon to execute "Open dashboard" :

http://localhost:1111/

Answer (score 0):

At the end of the installation process, the administration server starts automatically.
If you didn't install the service and you want to start the administration again you need to:

- go to the folder *dashboard* and run *ews-launcher.exe*
- or use the shortcut created in the Start Menu folder *EasyPHP Devserver 14.1 beta 2*

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution is to reinstall Easyphp, but still work for few days and after stop work, without apparent reasons. Easyphp team need to know this.

Before execute, backup all of your previous prinstallation files.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it worked in the following way:
I installed it and re-installed it several times, and in the end I wasn't able to see the dashboard.
I used the command indicated by Marcos and it helped, I could load the dashboard in the end.
Also, in order to have both services loaded, DB and HTTP, I loaded first the DB server and afterwards the HTTP server.
Hope this will help you,
Bogdan.